# Avoiding Multiple Joins to optimize the query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-performance

I have got a situation where I need to join 7 tables .

In this some tables have less records but Table1,Table2 and Table7 have huge records.

```
SELECT T2.id, 
       T2.name, 
       ------, 
       ------, 
       T7.name 
FROM   table1 T1                 # Table1 have 1 million Records 
       INNER JOIN table2 T2      # Table2 have half million Records 
               ON T1.id = T2.id 
       INNER JOIN table2 T3 
               ON T2.id = T3.id 
       INNER JOIN table2 T4 
               ON T3.id = T4.id 
       -------------- 
       --------------- 
       --------------- 
       INNER JOIN table7 T7      # Table7 have 1 million Records 
               ON T1.id = T7.id
```

I tried to filter these records load those in Temp Table

```
CREATE temporary TABLE Filter_Records_tmp 
  SELECT T.id, 
         T.name 
  FROM   table2 T 
  WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT id 
                 FROM   table1 
                 WHERE  id = T.id)
```

So that I can use Filtered records in Joining in place of Table1 and Table2.
But my question is same table1 I need to join with Table7.
How can I proceed on this ?

Any Suggestions.....

Comment: Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ and pay special attention to the section on query performance. Then ,please [edit] your question to tell us more about your tables and their indexes, so we can better help you. With tables as large as yours indexes make a vast difference.

Comment: @O.Jones for this tables only have Key relationships only(Every table have Primary key). No indexes have been there . In my question I'm asking how can i make Table1,Table2 and Table7 into one set use with other Joins

Comment: It is rare to have two table with the same Primary Key; it is really strange to have 8 such tables.  Please explain what the data is about.  Or, if you did not really mean for all of them to be `id`, then _please fix it_.